# Cordova how to install missing plugins after checkout project from repo?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I just cloned repository of the cordova app, but in .gitignore file added dir /plugins.

How can i install these missing plugins? U tried to find any config file where used plugins are saved, but without luck.

Many thanks for any advice.

Comment: my solution worked ?

Comment: Yes, but i must to remove packages.json from .gitignore file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you added the add_plugin & remove plugin hooks, your package.json shall have a cordovaPlugins list.

If yes, then, the solution that i used is to remove the platform and add it again to fetch for all plugins

```
cordova platform remove android
cordova platform add android
```

here are the needed hooks

**hooks/after_plugin_add/010_register_plugin.js**

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
/**
 * Push plugins to cordovaPlugins array after_plugin_add
 */
var fs = require('fs');
var packageJSON = require('../../package.json');

packageJSON.cordovaPlugins = packageJSON.cordovaPlugins || [];
process.env.CORDOVA_PLUGINS.split(',').forEach(function (plugin) {
  if(packageJSON.cordovaPlugins.indexOf(plugin) == -1) {
    packageJSON.cordovaPlugins.push(plugin);
  }
});

fs.writeFileSync('package.json', JSON.stringify(packageJSON, null, 2));
```

**hooks/after_plugin_rm/010_deregister_plugin.js**

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
/**
     * Remove plugins from cordovaPlugins array after_plugin_rm
     */
    var fs = require('fs');
    var packageJSON = require('../../package.json');

    packageJSON.cordovaPlugins = packageJSON.cordovaPlugins || [];

    process.env.CORDOVA_PLUGINS.split(',').forEach(function (plugin) {
      var index = packageJSON.cordovaPlugins.indexOf(plugin);
      if (index > -1) {
        packageJSON.cordovaPlugins.splice(index, 1);
      }
    });

    fs.writeFile('package.json', JSON.stringify(packageJSON, null, 2));
```

**hooks/after_platform_add/010_install_plugins.js**

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

/**
 * Install all plugins listed in package.json
 * https://raw.githubusercontent.com/diegonetto/generator-ionic/master/templates/hooks/after_platform_add/install_plugins.js
 */
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var path = require('path');
var sys = require('sys');

var packageJSON = require('../../package.json');
var cmd = process.platform === 'win32' ? 'cordova.cmd' : 'cordova';
// var script = path.resolve(__dirname, '../../node_modules/cordova/bin', cmd);

packageJSON.cordovaPlugins = packageJSON.cordovaPlugins || [];
packageJSON.cordovaPlugins.forEach(function (plugin) {
  exec('cordova plugin add ' + plugin, function (error, stdout, stderr) {
    sys.puts(stdout);
  });
});
```

One other solution is to add a task for plugin installation as described on this page :
http://jbavari.github.io/blog/2014/06/24/managing-cordova-plugins-with-package-dot-json-and-hooks/

Answer (score 15):

You can use `ionic state` to manage plugins and plateforms.

https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli#ionic-state

---

Read package.json and install listed plugins / plateforms :

```
ionic state restore
```

Save current plugins / platforms to the package.json :

```
ionic state save
```

Remove everything ! (including the default Ionic plugins  ...) :

```
ionic state clear
```

Remove everything and bring back what you have specified in your package.json :

```
ionic state reset
```

Comment: best answer, i use " ionic state restore" and every everything ready, thank

Answer (score 6):

`cordova prepare` seemed to do the trick for me.  After cloning my repository I was getting a "No platforms added to this project" error when running `cordova requirements`, even though the platforms were listed in the config.xml.  Running `cordova prepare` filled out the plugins directories, allowing`cordova requirements` to run.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

> ionic cordova prepare <platform>

It will give you the list of plugins that are not installed with error message.